# React navbar links don't work (Typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I made a NavBar with React that is not workink, or at least it does partially.
Clickin on the link the page does not change, although the address bar show the right address each time.
I was wondering it may be due to the fact I installed react-router-dom@5.2.0 with the latest react version? Cause I cannot find a single clue on the code (my bad)
Thank you in advance for your precious time!

APP.TSX

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Homepage from './Components/Homepage/Homepage';
import LoginPage from './Components/LoginPage/LoginPage';
import NavBar from './Components/NavBar/NavBar';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <NavBar />
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/' exact component={Homepage} />
        <Route path='/login' component={LoginPage} />
      </Switch>

    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

NAVBAR.TSX

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './NavBar.module.css';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function NavBar() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.navbarWrapper}>
      <ul className={styles.navbar}>
        <li><Link to='/'>Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link to='/login'>Login</Link></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

PACKAGE.JSON

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.59",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.8.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: why you're using switch instead of rapping route inside the routes.

Comment: Because Routes replaced Switch from v6, as I said I've installed v5.2.0